# Regarding Retrofit 1.9.0 DELETE request with body

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Retrofit 1.9.0 used in my application.I need `DELETE` request with body and call back `method.My` interface is

```
@DELETE("/Notifications/Remove")     
public void notificationDelete(@Body NotificationDeleteInput obj,Callback<CommonResponse> mCallback)
```

When I use this given error  Non-body `HTTP method` cannot contain `@Body` or `@TypedOutput`. and Only one `Http` is `allowed.Found:DELETE` and `DELETE`. Please help me how to overcome this error.

Comment: sending body in a delete request doesn't make sense if you're following REST principles..

Comment: @akash93,Thank you for your reply.Is there anyway to use Delete request for above mentioned API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because Retrofit sets `hasBody` to `false` by default for delete requests . This is OK since it makes no sense to send a body with a DELETE request. However Http spec doesn't explicitly forbid this..

As a hack you can create your own `Delete`annotation overwriting the retrofit  `Delete` annotation as follows:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RestMethod(value = "DELETE", hasBody = true)
@interface MOD_DELETE {
  String value();
}
```

and then  in your request use `@MOD_DELETE` instead of `@DELETE`

Comment: How can i pass obj(json format entity)instead of string value();